# using Spring property when initializing a class

Tags: java, spring

The following produces a null error ("A" is null), but I am not sure why.  Is the bean instantiated before the property value is set?

```
package org.ets.readtogether.queuing;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("Abean")
public class Test {

    @Value("${send.timeout.secs}")
    public Integer A;

    public int B = A * 1000;
}
```

Comment: Well yeah, how do you set a field without there being an object?

Comment: You can also use SpEL in the `@Value` annotation: `@Value("#{systemProperties['send.timeout.secs'] * 1000}")`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
@Component("Abean")
public class Test {

    @Value("${send.timeout.secs}")
    public Integer A;

    public int B;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
       B = A * 1000;
    }
}
```

Good example [here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-postconstruct-and-predestroy-example/)

Answer (score 2):

Spring adds all the dependencies injected in an object after instantiating it. Object instantiation precedes any `@Autowired` dependency injection or `@Value` value assignment done by Spring.

The instantiation of your class's object fails even before Spring has the object to inject dependencies because the statement `public int B = A * 1000;` is called during object instantiation.

In order to assign the variable `B` a value **after** Spring has finished all injections, perform the operation in either a `@PostConstruct` method or in an `@AutoWired` constructor.

```
   public int B; // remove the assignment here.

   @PostConstruct
   public void postConstruct () {
       this.B = A * 1000;
   }
```

The above method would be called after the object has been instantiated and after Spring has done its work.